# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined in socket

Tags: node.js

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    var ip = socket.client.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.client.conn.remoteAddress || socket.conn.remoteAddress || socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(ip)
    console.log('user ket noi ' + clients)
    clients++

    //io.emit("new msg", { msg: `Hiện tại có ${clients} đang kết nối !!` });    
    io.broadcast.emit("new msg", { msg: `Hiện tại có ${clients} đang kết nối !!` });    


    socket.on('on-chat', data => {
    io.emit('user-chat', data)
})
    
})
```

file index.js , i can't use io.broadcast.emit but i can use io.emit how can i fix pls ;( i'm newbie

error in cmd

C:\Users\Admin\Documents\heroku\Chat-real-time\index.js:34
io.broadcast.emit("new msg", { msg: `Hiện tại có ${clients} đang kết nối !!` });
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
at Namespace. (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\heroku\Chat-real-time\index.js:34:15)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Namespace.emitReserved (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\heroku\Chat-real-time\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:56:22)
at C:\Users\Admin\Documents\heroku\Chat-real-time\node_modules\socket.io\dist\namespace.js:141:26
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To broadcast you need to call it from the socket instance not the io instance. So it would be:

```
socket.broadcast.emit()
```

You can read more about emitting events in the [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events/)